# need help on php code creating error wordpress custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I've put this code for slider to show posts picking up category of user choice category, but after adding this code it's not picking after custom fields e.g  or any other php code even i've tried..

Here's the code i've applied

```
<div class="blog-posts-slider">
 <?php $temp_query = $wp_query;
                $category_name = get_field('business_solutions_category_name');     
                     query_posts(array(
                            'category_name' =>  $category_name,
                            'posts_per_page' => 5
                    )
                 ); 
                 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                 $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                 $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                 ?>

                 <div class="slider-single-post">
                    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image : url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"></div>
                    <div class="slider-post-text">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; 
                $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
</div>
```

i am not familiar that much with php.. but i think it's error on endwhile or below that line.. i'm missing something..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use get_post_custom incorrectly. From the codex,
>   [get_post_custom](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)
>
> Returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a
>   particular post or page.

```
get_post_custom($post_id);
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get you..
i have to use something incorrectly? 
and i used get_field('business_solutions_category_name');
to get the value of custom field plugin(FIELD) i'm using that plugin.
am i ending loop correct?

Comment: Warning: urlencode() expects parameter1 to be string.
here's an error i got now, after that code.

Comment: i've put another answer to show you the code, it was lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Problem is, custom fields aren't working for the div class-above-footer.
<div class="blog-posts-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Connect with C-Level Executives</h2>
                <div class="blog-posts-slider">

                   <?php $temp_query = $wp_query;
                    $category_name = get_field('business_solutions_category_name');     
                         query_posts(array(
                                'category_name' =>  $category_name,
                                'posts_per_page' => 5
                        )
                     ); 
                     while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                     $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                     $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                     $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                     ?>

                     <div class="slider-single-post">
                        <div class="blog-image" style="background-image : url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"></div>
                        <div class="slider-post-text">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php endwhile; 
                    $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="above-footer-link">
            <div class="container">
                <h2><?php the_field('business_solutions_abovefooter_heading');?></h2>
                <a href="<?php the_field('business_solutions_abovefooter_button_link');?>"><?php the_field('business_solutions_abovefooter_button_text');?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```